# When to use "0" and when to use "1"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What is difference from 0 to 1 in the following formulae?

Example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),"No Match","Match")
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,1)),"No Match","Match")
```

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH` is used in the following way:

```
=MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

where `[match_type]` is optional and can be of the following:

- `1` - Less than
- `0` - Exact match
- `-1` - Greater than

Comment: ...also if you have a match type of 1 values should be sorted ascending - for exact match with match type 0 values don't need to be sorted

Answer (score -1):

Well as one should expect, ISERROR returns True as 1 and False as 0. so it's saying if there's an error in that match statement. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php  so if that match statement returns one of those values office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/… "#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME? or #NULL" if you do ISERROR(value) and value is any of those then that returns True.

This page here http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php
says that "If the MATCH function does not find a match, it will return a #N/A error."

An if statement has 3 parts. The condition, and what if true and what if false. True here is referring to the ISERROR function returning True i.e. a no match. False would be the ISERROR function giving no error i.e. a match.

So, it looks like it'll print "No Match" in the cell, if the match function returns with n/a, i.e. if there's no match. And it will print "Match" in the cell if the match function returns a value(i.e. not an n/a, not an error).